# Install Gems Into a Project Bundle Using Another Bundle or Installed Gem Folder as The Source

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundle, bundler

I've got dozens of Ruby projects using Bundler, each with their own gem bundle in ./vendor. I'd like to be able to do something like this at the top of my Gemfile:

```
source 'file:///Users/midwire/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352'
```

But this doesn't seem to work unless I'm not doing it right. Is there a way to accomplish this, or possibly a way to just copy gems from another project's bundle or from my global installed gem repository in:

```
/Users/midwire/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352
```

It just seems a bit inefficient to be hitting the wire every time I install the `pry` gem when I've already got it on my hard drive in 78 locations.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `source` directive refers to a [RubyGems server](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/18).

```
$ gem server -d /Users/midwire/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/ --daemon
```

Using a localhost `source` in Gemfile:

```
source 'http://127.0.0.1:8808/' # port is usually required
```

I believe what you want is the ability to specify a local filepath to the gem:

```
gem 'my_gem', '1.0.0', :path => '/Users/midwire/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/...'
```

Comment: Thanks Adam, that would work perfectly for a single gem. I'd like to be able to copy multiple gems from a given bundle or gem path if possible. It appears that one may be able to unpack the gems and sort our the spec files, doc, etc into their appropriate folders inside the bundle directory. I just wondered if their is a way already designed to do this without resorting to using `cp x y` and then tweaking the Gemfile.lock file.

Comment: Nice solution and just what I was looking for.  Thanks Adam!